# What is the dependent variable in an Item Count Technique Regression (List experiment)

Tags: multiple-regression, maximum-likelihood, regression-coefficients, experiment-design

I try to understand the logic behind an Item Count Technique Regression (Imai 2011; Blair & Imai 2012). I am especially interested in the ML estimator for the multivariate regression analysis (Blair & Imai 2012, p. 53).

I understand the logic of a list experiment, but I do not fully understand what is estimated in the multivariate regression model. Is the dependent variable the number of items a participant agrees with, or is it the likelihood that a participant agreed with the sensitive item? Or is it something completely different?

An example from the help file of the list experiment R package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/list/list.pdf):

```
library(list)
data(race)
set.seed(1)
# Fit linear regression
# Replicates Table 1 Columns 1-2 Imai (2011); note that age is divided by 10
lm.results <- ictreg(y ~ south + age + male + college, data = race,
treat = "treat", J=3, method = "lm")
summary(lm.results)
```

The results:

```
Item Count Technique Regression 

Call: ictreg(formula = y ~ south + age + male + college, data = race, 
    treat = "treat", J = 3, method = "lm")

Sensitive item 
                Est.    S.E.
(Intercept) -0.43430 0.16033
south        0.20198 0.11760
age          0.07309 0.03051
male         0.18023 0.09846
college      0.11446 0.09775

Control items 
                Est.    S.E.
(Intercept)  2.40606 0.10511
south       -0.18021 0.07450
age          0.02047 0.01998
male        -0.20177 0.06522
college     -0.39408 0.06406

Residual standard error: 0.837231 with 1203 degrees of freedom

Number of control items J set to 3. Treatment groups were indicated by '' and '' and the control group by ''.
```

I get that I am mainly interested in the first part ("Sensitive Item"). But what do the coefficients represent?

---

*References*

Blair, G., & Imai, K. (2012). Statistical Analysis of List Experiments. Political Analysis, 20(01), 47–77. https://doi.org/10.1093/pan/mpr048

Imai, K. (2011). Multivariate Regression Analysis for the Item Count Technique. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 106(494), 407–416. https://doi.org/10.1198/jasa.2011.ap10415